# Display items depending select choice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to display a something depending the selection of the drop down menu.

For example, if I select blue I want a menu for blue, if red menu for red, ...

each selection must have a index for binding object, but I'm lost

Now the selection menu display only color but binding to nowhere

If someone of you have a solution

```
<div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
          <h1>Selection</h1>
    <div v-for="car in cars">
      <v-select
        label="Selection"
        :items="car.version"
        item-text="color"
      >
      </v-select>
      <v-btn @click="addIntensity">
        add intensity
      </v-btn>
      <br>
      <br>

      </v-text-field>
      <div v-for="(int, index) in intensity">
        index{{index}}
        <v-btn @click="delIntensity(index)">
        delete intensity
      </v-btn>
        <v-text-field
                      label="In"
                      type="number"
                      min="1"
                      max="100"
                      v-model="int.in">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
                      label="Out"
                      type="number"
                      min="1"
                      max="100"
                      v-model="int.out">
        </v-text-field>
      </div>
    </div>
      </v-app>
    </div>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        sizeValue: 0,
        intensity:[
              {in: 0, out: 0}],
        cars: [
              {
              name: 'McQueen',
              version: [
              {color: 'blue' },                      
              {color: 'red' },
              {color: 'green' },
              {color: 'purple' },
              ]
             }
           ],
      }),
      methods: {
        addIntensity() {
          this.$set(this.intensity, this.intensity.length, {in: 0, out: 0});
        },
        delIntensity(index) {
          this.intensity.splice(index, 1);
        }
      },
      created() {
        for(var i = 0; i <= val;i++){
          this.$set(this.intensity, i, {in: 0, out: 0});
        }
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the intensity array to object and dynamically set the key as selected color and value as intensity

Here in the below code, I've dynamically setting the vue reactivity data by using this.$set

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/XWWermb?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <h1>Selection</h1>
<div v-for="car in cars">
  <v-select
    v-model="selectedColor"
    label="Selection"
    :items="car.version"
    item-text="color"
  >
  </v-select>
  <v-btn @click="addIntensity" v-if="selectedColor">
    add intensity
    </v-btn>
    <br>
    <br>
  <div v-for="(int, index) in intensity[selectedColor]">

    Index - {{index}}
    <v-btn @click="delIntensity(index)">
    delete intensity
  </v-btn>
    <v-text-field
                  label="In"
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  max="100"
                  v-model="int.in">
    </v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
                  label="Out"
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  max="100"
                  v-model="int.out">
    </v-text-field>
  </div>
</div>
        <v-checkbox label="Apply to All" v-model="checkboxAll"></v-checkbox>
        <v-checkbox label="In = Out" v-model="checkboxInOut"></v-checkbox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    checkboxInOut: false,
    checkboxAll: false,
    sizeValue: 0,
    intensity:{},
    selectedColor: '',
    cars: [
          {
          name: 'McQueen',
          version: [
          {color: 'blue' },                      
          {color: 'red' },
          {color: 'green' },
          {color: 'purple' },
          ]
         }
       ],
  }),
  methods: {
    addIntensity() {
      this.$set(this.intensity[this.selectedColor], this.intensity[this.selectedColor].length, {in: 0, out: 0});
    },
    delIntensity(index) {
      this.intensity[this.selectedColor].splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    checkboxInOut(val) {
      if (val) {
        this.intensity[this.selectedColor].forEach(x => {
          x.out  = x.in;
        });
      }
    },
    selectedColor(val) {
      if (!this.intensity[val]) {
        this.$set(this.intensity, val, [{in: 0, out: 0}]);
      }
    }
  }
})
```